# I am helping to fix a php site that has many unwanted links index.php/[unwanted_links]

Tags: php

A friend has a php site that somehow has many unwanted links that shows up in the site in some situation.

Below I will use "site" to refer to the site domain.

```
site redirects to site/greetings/ (a laravel site)
```

There are many sections linked from a list of menu.

```
site/greetings/all
site/greetings/new
site/greetings/birthday
site/greetings/newyear
...
```

In some situation, in the list of menu on the site, the top 3 items are replaced with the following links.

```
site/greetings/index.php/online-dating-reality/
site/greetings/index.php/dating-for-you/
site/greetings/index.php/dating-services-in-tampa-fl/
```

A user reported this when he is using an Android 7.1.1 tablet and Chrome browser.  We are not able to reproduce the problem with our table and phones, but the links do show up in google search when we search on them.

We are not able to find the links in the code. How do I go about fixing this problem?  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the site/server has been hacked. Chances are if you do manage to remove the links they will comeback if you don't find and remove the hack and patch the vulnerability that has been exploited.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to go about figuring out the hacks?

Comment: If you don't know how to do that then I recommend seeking professional advice.

Answer (score 1):

Either there is some sort of unwanted behavior in your site, or someone has taken control of your site.

Either way, there is only one thing to do: nuke it from orbit. Now. Don't wait. Don't try to fix it. Don't try to figure it out. Nuke the entire server and everything on it. There is a high probability that it is no longer "your" server.

*Immediately* disconnect any sort of network access. Physically! Pull out all network cables, physically remove all wireless network adapters. Then, and *only* then can you start examining the server. *Never* connect it to any network ever again.

*Do not* bring the site back again, *until* you have fully understood what happened.

Then, restore from an *old* backup that you know 100% to be from *before* the compromise. Use your understanding of the breach to plug any holes, remove any backdoors, fix any bugs that could potentially have lead to the problem. Use static and dynamic analysis tools to look for similar defects in your code base. Make sure you have updated all components of the system, from the CPU microcode, the UEFI, the OS, the libraries, PHP, Laravel, and any other libraries and tools you use. Do a full code audit, preferably with an outside third-party (you yourself might be blinded by the close involvement in the project).

Then, and *only then* can you bring the site back.

Let me re-iterate: once you lost control of your server *once*, it is no longer your server, and it never will be again. There is an infinite number of places where an attacker may have hidden a backdoor, and all it takes is you overlooking one of those. You can reuse the casing, the PSU, but anything which has a processor and some writeable memory on it (such as the motherboard with its EEPROM, a harddisk with its firmware, etc.) must be treated as compromised and destroyed.

Comment: That sucks:-(  Thanks for the suggestion.